# I want to get the numbered list like in MS Word

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I have written -

```
    $('#comment_content').keypress(function(key) {
      if (key.which == 13) {
        if(matched = content.match(/\n\d\./g)) {
          console.log(matched);
          $('#comment_content').val(content + "\n" + ++matched + ".")
          key.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
```

'#comment_content' is the id of the textarea.
I want something like in MS word

1. Some Text (press Enter key)

(new line)2. Some text

(new line)3.

I'm unable to get the result need help.

Comment: What exactly are you battling with? Are you not just looking for the `<ol>` tag?

Comment: Well, the logic I have written related to regex is not perfect. No, actually I haven't used ol tag for this.

Comment: Or can you suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is an issue - the content won't start with a newline character, it'll start with number and a dot:

```
$('#comment_content').keypress(function(key) {
  var content = $('#comment_content').val();
  if (key.which == 13) {
    if(matched = content.match(/^\d\./)) {
      console.log("matched numbered list start!: "+ matched);
      $('#comment_content').val(content + "\n" + ++ matched + ".")
      key.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaewnjcL/4/)

Comment: it's not giving the result I wanted as it's not incrementing after 2.